# How to persist entity with business rules?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com) for my project. And I have an entity as shown in the code snippet below.

```
public class Transaction : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    protected Transaction()
    {
        TransactionState = TransactionState.Uncompleted;
    }

    public TransactionState TransactionState { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Loan Loan { get; protected set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    // ...

    public async Task CompleteAsync(ICoreBankingService coreBankingService, IRepository<Transaction, Guid> transactionRepository)
    {
        try
        {
            // Perform a series of compulsory actions in some given sequence with coreBankingService that might throw exception
            Loan.SetSomeStuffThatOriginatedFromMotherTransaction();
            TransactionState = TransactionState.Completed;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception and set this Transaction entity state appropriately
            TransactionState = TransactionState.Failed;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure by all means to persist the resulting the entity within itself
            await transactionRepository.UpdateAsync(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand I should separate persistence from the entity (which by the way, is an architecture provided by [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com) out of the box! using [Application Services](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Articles/Developing-MultiTenant-SaaS-ASP.NET-CORE-Angular/index.html#applicationservices)).

However, I **NEED** to make certain that I *perform a series of compulsory actions in some given sequence with `coreBankingService`* and persist changes at each stage of these computations on the `Transaction` entity, hence the reason for my naive and probably wrong approach.

Please, what is the right approach to this kind of problem? How do I persist states of an entity that results from a computation or action within the same entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose `internal` methods that change the state:

```
public class Transaction : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    protected Transaction()
    {
        TransactionState = TransactionState.Uncompleted;
    }

    public TransactionState TransactionState { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Loan Loan { get; protected set; }
    // ...

    internal void Abort()
    {
        TransactionState = TransactionState.Failed;
    }

    internal void Complete()
    {
        TransactionState = TransactionState.Completed;
    }
}
```

And define the domain service in the same assembly:

```
public class TransactionManager : DomainService
{
    private readonly ICoreBankingService _coreBankingService;
    private readonly LoanManager _loanManager;
    private readonly IRepository<Transaction, Guid> _transactionRepository;

    public TransactionManager(
        ICoreBankingService coreBankingService,
        LoanManager loanManager,
        IRepository<Transaction, Guid> transactionRepository)
    {
        _coreBankingService = coreBankingService;
        _loanManager = loanManager;
        _transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }

    public async Task TryCompleteAsync(Transaction transaction)
    {
        try
        {
            // Use _coreBankingService to do something that might throw exception
            _coreBankingService.DoSomething();
            _loanManager.SetSomeStuffThatOriginatedFromMotherTransaction(transaction.Loan);
            transaction.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception and abort the Transaction
            transaction.Abort();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure by all means to persist the resulting the entity
            await _transactionRepository.UpdateAsync(transaction);
        }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
await _transactionManager.TryCompleteAsync(transaction);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Sometimes thinking about the right approach/architecture to solve a problem can be very challenging for a rookie programmer like me.